# Max # subdirectories on Linux box

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory-structure

One of the things my Java application running on Linux is doing creating directories. All directories are created in /a/b/c, which at this point contains 31998 subdirs.

Evidently this is enough to not allow any more to be created.

With this 2 questions:

- Why?
- How can i know what the max number is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your filesystem. The following thread has more information on the limits of various filesystems:

[What is the maximum number of folders allowed in a folder in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/66331/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-folders-allowed-in-a-folder-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Wikipedia for ext2, ext3, ext4, xfs and reiserfs. That should provide you your answer.

Probably you should also read [this](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/xfs/datasheet.pdf):